# cannot run jfrog executable from inside alpine linux container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, jfrog-mission-control

I am using an `alpine linux` container and specifically `python:3.4-alpine` and `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`. When I try to execute any script or executable that I have placed in the executable I get `Not Found` error.

For example. When in the `python:3.4-alpine` container I want to install `jfrog` I follow the command [here](https://www.jfrog.com/getcli/) (after I install `curl` via apk). This command downloads a shell script and pipes it to sh which downloads and creates a `jfrog` executable with the correct permissions. When I am trying to run this executable I am getting

> bin/sh: ./jfrog: not found

**update**

I discovered that the root user is using `bin/ash` by default, which I have no idea what it is. So I invoked `bin/sh jfrog` manually and I get

> / # bin/sh jfrog
>   jfrog: line 1: ELF: not found
>   jfrog: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I suspect that it has to do with only root user existing in the container.

Comment: I think we need more details. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure but the jfrog executable is dynamically linked, and with `ldd jfrog` you get :

```
ldd jfrog
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ffb4c8d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ffb4c8d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x55ffb4c8d000)
```

As you can see you have libc dependencies, and alpine come with musl.
You can try to add `apk add libc6-compat` but I'm not sure it will work

Comment: nope :/ i think I will have to use curl instead of `jfrog`

Answer (score 4):

the problem is, that jfrog cli was compiled against glibc and alpine linux only provides uclibc. To make it run under alpine its not trivial, you have to install a sandbox that is bigger than then alpine env. https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs

Another possibility is to compile the jfrog binary yourself in alpine. This Dockerfile worked for me.

```
FROM golang:alpine
WORKDIR /app/
RUN apk update && apk add git

# checkout the latest tag of jfrog cli
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/jfrogdev/jfrog-cli-go \
 && git clone https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go /go/src/github.com/jfrogdev/jfrog-cli-go\
 && cd /go/src/github.com/jfrogdev/jfrog-cli-go \
 && git checkout $(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)

RUN GOOS=linux go get github.com/jfrogdev/jfrog-cli-go/jfrog

FROM alpine
COPY --from=0 /go/bin/jfrog /usr/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["jfrog"]
```

Comment: I got an error about "You are not currently on a branch." when trying to use that dockerfile

Comment: Had to use `RUN GOOS=linux go get github.com/jfrogdev/jfrog-cli-go/jfrog-cli/jfrog` instead

Answer (score 1):

The script you are running begins with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Bash is not included with alpine by default. You can install it with:

```
apk update && apk add bash
```

Note that alpine is fairly stripped down by design, so there may be other missing dependencies that you'll need to add to make this script work.

Comment: I made the question a bit more specific because it turns out that my problem is specifically how to run `jfrog` on alpine linux container. Your suggestion solved the issue for the `ubuntu` container though

Answer (score 1):

May be too late, but this probably might help someone else.

```
RUN curl -Lo /usr/bin/jfrog https://api.bintray.com/content/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/\$latest/jfrog-cli-linux-386/jfrog?bt_package=jfrog-cli-linux-386 \
    && chmod a+x /usr/bin/jfrog
```

[(Click Here for Reference Link)](https://gitlab.com/figaw/alpine-jfrog-cli/blob/master/Dockerfile#L10-11)